# JAVA JPA ValidationException

Tags: java, exception, jpa

I have a problem with one JPA exception when I want to insert row in database I got this exception:

```
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-7124] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: An unsuccessful writeChanges() has been called on this UnitOfWork.  Given the danger that partial changes have been written to the datastore but not rolled back (if inside external transaction), the only supported operations now are release, global transaction rollback, any non-object level query or SQLCall execution.  The operation commit was attempted.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commitInternal(EntityTransactionImpl.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:63)
    at database.TarpineManager.commitTransaction(TarpineManager.java:23)
    at gijos.InsertToDB.insertLink(InsertToDB.java:57)
    at gijos.LygiagretusIrasymas.run(LygiagretusIrasymas.java:26)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7124] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: An unsuccessful writeChanges() has been called on this UnitOfWork.  Given the danger that partial changes have been written to the datastore but not rolled back (if inside external transaction), the only supported operations now are release, global transaction rollback, any non-object level query or SQLCall execution.  The operation commit was attempted.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.unitOfWorkAfterWriteChangesFailed(ValidationException.java:1802)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitAndResume(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1119)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.commitInternal(EntityTransactionImpl.java:84)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: What's your question? You are clearly attempting to insert to some column something that doesn't belong there. Without some code to see, we can't tell you what.

Answer (score 3):

1. You have a javax.persistence.RollbackException
2. This is only raised when EntityTransaction.commit() fails
3. The underlying cause within EclipseLink is org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException An unsuccessful writeChanges() has been called on this UnitOfWork. 
   Given the danger that partial changes have been written to the
   datastore but not rolled back (if inside external transaction), the
   only supported operations now are release, global transaction
   rollback, any non-object level query or SQLCall execution.  The
   operation commit was attempted.

You need to provide some code or some description of your transactions up to this point.

I think maybe you:
 1. started a transaction, updated/persisted data, failed on the commit, received a RollbackException
 2. continued to use the same entity objects in the same persistence context and received another RollbackException.  This is illegal.  The first time you receive a RollbackException, you must clear the persistence context and start over:

If this is try: use `EntityManager.clear()` in your error handling code, then re-retrieve objects before you start a new transaction.